# Question on the use of AUC in cost sensitive learning

Tags: supervised-learning

Why is the AUC not appropriate to use as an evaluation metric in cost sensitive learning?

I have read the book *Applied Predictive Modeling* written by Max Kuhn. As he wrote in the book,

> The class probabilities cannot be generated for the model, at least in the available implementation. Therefore we cannot calculate an ROC curve. [Page 431]

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Comment: Do you know how to calculate an ROC curve?

Comment: @MatthewDrury kind of. Could you please give me some explanations, especially in the case of neural network training process.